# increase clickable area around tiny icon

Tags: icons, font-awesome, area, clickable

i am using the font awesome icon ellipsis-v (which is very tiny; [see here](http://fontawesome.io/icon/ellipsis-v/)) in a clickable row, so it's frustrating to click, because most of the time you end up clicking on the row.
i tried putting the link on the td, but it's not working (because the whole row is clickable?).

are there any css tricks to increase the clickable area around the fa-icon?
(below the code i tried)

```
<tr class='clickable-row' data-href='details.html'>
  <td></td>
  <td class="client-status"><span class="label label-warning"></span></td>
  <td>
    <a class="doDropdown">
      <div class="ibox-tools">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle doDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="details.html">View</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="details_edit.html">Edit</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the property line-height or font-size on <**i**> tag:
Example:

```
i {  
line-height: 20px;  
font-size: 20px;  
}
```

Comment: thank you! i directly added it to .fa-ellipsis-v, it makes the icon bigger. but then it won't fit into my design. i may could create a clickable div with the icon inside. gonna try this

Comment: No problem. Just give your desired values to it, I have used 20px as an example only.
Also, mark my answer as correct @abchacker :P

Comment: it didn't fix my problem 100%. i don't want the icon to get bigger, i want it the same size but with a clickable area around it so it's easier for the user to click the icon. line-height works for the vertical part, what would it be for the horizontal part? because there is no line-width right?

Comment: Put it inside a **div** and then give it some class, then style that class with some padding. Something like: .classOnDiv { padding: 20px }

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `fa-nx` inside the icon class, where `n` is the number and it simply increases the icon's size by `n` times its original.

Below `n` is 2. You can use 3, 4.. depending on your design.

```html
<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```